# Is there something that can completely prevent the effects of the Hold Person spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, saving-throw, conditions

I have been listening through [Glass Cannon](https://glasscannonpodcast.com/), and just got through the episode where they were all *hold person*ed and monologued at by Brandor. 
I am still relatively new to *Pathfinder*, but I was wondering if there was an item or something that could completely prevent being affected by *hold person*?

I think the most I can probably do is items that boost my save but I was hoping for a more guaranteed way to prevent it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 14):

### [*Freedom of Movement*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-of-movement)

The spell *freedom of movement* protects the subject from magical spells and other effects that would normally prevent or impede their movement, which includes the [paralyzed condition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Paralyzed) as inflicted by the spell *[hold person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person/)*. Cast in advance, it will protect you from being the victim of such a spell.

More permanently, you could also acquire a magic item such as a [*ring of freedom of movement*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-freedom-of-movement/), which permanently grants the wearer the benefit of the aforementioned spell. It is a quite costly item, though, and usually beyond the means of characters at lower levels.

Answer (score 2):

A [ring of counterspells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-counterspells/) when charged with [hold person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person/) would fit your requirement.

However, this works ONCE. Youll have to save against another casting.

Answer (score 2):

### [*Animal Soul*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/animal-soul/)

If you have a the mount class feature or an animal companion, you can take this feat and choose to ignore Hold Person at all times (because Hold Person only works on people, not animals).